# How to make 2 rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I use a rule like this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /project/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The result is my page using `www.myweb.com/index.php?page=about` becomes `www.myweb.com/About.html`

My problem is if I direct to `user.php` and create a page like `www.myweb.com/user.php?page=NewPage`, the result can not be like this `www.myweb.com/NewPage.html`.

I've added a rule like this one in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /project/user.php?page=$1 [L]
```

How to add a rule for my case?

Comment: There seems to be no way to determine where to send what request. The server doesn't know you want `About.html` to go to `index.php` and `NewPage.html` to go to `user.php`. There needs to be something different between these URLs to be used with rewrite.

Comment: page=1&rule=1 and page=2&rule=2

Comment: All `anything.html` should go to `user.php`, except `about.html` that goes to `index.php`. Is that right or are there other exceptions?

Comment: @faa : No, there are still some pages that are in index.php. Is it possible?